# What is this strange plant called?

Tags: identification, houseplants

I bought this plant from a university plant sale when it was much smaller. What is it called? How big can it get?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is Sansevieria cylindrica, a tender succulent plant sometimes commonly known as African Spear. It is a relative of Sansevieria fasciata, commonly known by various names such as Mother In Law's Tongue or Snake Plant. Eventual height of this one varies between 12-24 inches - it should not be over watered or it will rot, and the pot should have drainage holes. Water only when the surface of the potting soil is dry - when you do water, water thoroughly, and always empty any outer pot or tray after 30 minutes so its not left sitting in water. If you decide to repot at any time, it is usually recommended to  use cactus potting mix to reduce the risk of rot,  though I've had mine for years growing in perfectly ordinary multi purpose potting soil. It  tolerates low light situations indoors, but does better in bright light,though direct sun in summer indoors is not advised. Average room temperatures, don't stand near any heat sources such as radiators. Can be grown outdoors in warmer regions in partial shade, more information here https://www.thespruce.com/grow-sansevieria-cylindrica-1902732